# Write a numpy array to headerless wav file?

Tags: python, numpy, wav, soundfile, mu-law

I have a numpy audio array, I would like to write it in chunks as **wav** with **ulaw** encoding. For now I am using the [soundfile](https://python-soundfile.readthedocs.io/en/0.11.0/index.html?highlight=write#soundfile.SoundFile.write) library:

```py
import soundfile as sf
# ...
audio_len = len(audio) # numpy array
chunkLen = int(0.030 * 8000)
for i in range(0, audio_len, chunkLen):
     chunk = audio[i:min(i+chunkLen, audio_len)]
     buffered = BytesIO()
     sf.write(buffered, chunk, samplerate=8000, format="WAV", subtype="ULAW")
     buffered.seek(0)
     yield buffered.read()
```

However, the returned raw data file includes a lot of `\bRIFF`, which means it is still writing headers, is there anyway I can write it as headerless?

Comment: RIFF WAV is a container format. As such it always wraps a stream with protocol data. `\bRIFF` is a marker for this. If it wouldn't be there, it wouldn't be a WAV file. If you don't want any extra data, just dump the numpy array to a file.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for your reply! Returning by chunks is actually required by the client which is why I’m trying to find a solution for this snippet. Do you know any workaround for this function requirements? On top of my head I can think of writing the audio to get a byte string then find the data chunk of the wav. But clients prefer the raw format